# Rails 4 ActiveAdmin - undefined local variable or method `collection_before_scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a strange problem with my ActiveAdmin resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ServicePage do
  menu priority: 5

  permit_params :title, :body, :slug, :published

  config.sort_order = 'created_at_desc'
  config.per_page = 10

  scope :all, default: true
  scope :published
  scope :not_published

  filter :title
  filter :slug
end
```

When I try to access index page for it, I get `undefined local variable or method 'collection_before_scope' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::Scopes:0x007f4c8ecdfa28>` error.

When I remove those 3 `scope`'s, I get `Collection is not a paginated scope. Set collection.page(params[:page]).per(10) before calling :paginated_collection.`

But if only I change code to `ActiveAdmin.register ServicePage, as: 'page' do`, all seems to become ok. I am sure, that when I've just added ServicePage resource to ActiveAdmin, it worked. Can someone tell me, what's going on?

(Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.1.6, active_admin 1.0.0.pre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my ApplicationController, in this code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_service_pages

  # ...

  def set_service_pages
    @service_pages = ServicePage.published
  end
end
```

If I change the @service_pages variable name, all starts to work again. So the solution for me was to add

```
controller do
  skip_before_filter :set_service_pages
end
```

in my ActiveAdmin's ServicePage resource.

By the way, why does ActiveAdmin even care about my variable names?

Comment: ActiveAdmin (Inherited Resources) automatically instantiates variables corresponding to your resources, which may cause a collision like here.